# Help me write a SQL Crosstab query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I have 3 tables that look like this:

```
tblVideo:
    VideoID     |   Video Name
          1             video 1
          2             video 2
          3             video 3
          4             video 4

tblCategory:
    CategoryID  |   CategoryName
          1           category1
          2           category2
          3           category3

tblVideoCategory:
     VideoID    |    CategoryID
          1               3
          2               1
          2               2
          3               1
          3               2
          3               3
          4               1
```

and I would like to write a query that would return a table that looks like this:

```
vVideoCategory:
VideoID   |   VideoName   |   category1   |   category2   |   category3
   1           video 1           false           false          true 
   2           video 2           true            true           false
   3           video 3           true            true           true
   4           video 4           true            false          false
```

I've tried looking around for examples but haven't quite found anything that seems the same.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Definitely looking for something that allows for changing and adding/deleting categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT v.videoid,
         v.video_name,
         COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN vc.categoryid = 1 THEN 'true' END), 'false') AS category1,
         COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN vc.categoryid = 2 THEN 'true' END), 'false') AS category2,
         COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN vc.categoryid = 3 THEN 'true' END), 'false') AS category3
    FROM tblvideo v
    JOIN tblvideocategory vc ON vc.videoid = v.videoid
GROUP BY v.videoid, v.video_name
```

SQL Server 2005+:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @categoryid AS INT

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
   SELECT c.categoryid
     FROM tblcategory c
 ORDER BY c.categoryid

SET @SQL = N'SELECT v.videoid,
                    v.video_name, '

OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @categoryid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  SET @SQL = @SQL + ' COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN vc.categoryid = '+ @categoryid +' THEN 'true' END), 'false') AS category'+ @categoryid +' ,'

  FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @categoryid
END

CLOSE CUR;
DEALLOCATE CUR;

--Get rid of trailing comma at the end
SELECT @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL, 1, LEN(@SQL) -1)

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM tblvideo v
                    JOIN tblvideocategory vc ON vc.videoid = v.videoid
                GROUP BY v.videoid, v.video_name 
                ORDER BY v.videoid, v.video_name '

BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

Comment: @OMG - What if there is no limit to the number of categories?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: If that's the case, dynamic SQL.  But the OP hasn't specified which database to provide information on whose dynamic SQL syntax to use.

Comment: should have specified, i do want to have dynamic categories

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005, but I could install 2008 instead

Comment: @matthew_360: There's no need to move to 2005 for this.  I updated to add a dynamic SQL example.

Comment: that ended up working perfectly, thanks OMG. I changed it just a little bit:

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to expand a little bit on what OMG Ponies provided me with:

```
@"            
            DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(4000)
            DECLARE @categoryid AS INT

            DECLARE CUR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
               SELECT c.categoryid
                 FROM Category c
             ORDER BY c.categoryid

            SET @SQL = 'SELECT v.videoid, v.title, v.Tags, '

            OPEN CUR
            FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @categoryid
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
              SET @SQL = @SQL + ' COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN vc.categoryid = ' + str(@categoryid) + ' THEN ''true'' END), ''false'') AS [category' + ltrim(str(@categoryid)) + '] ,'
              FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @categoryid
            END

            CLOSE CUR;
            DEALLOCATE CUR;

            --Get rid of trailing comma at the end
            SELECT @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL, 1, LEN(@SQL) -1)

            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM Video v
                                LEFT JOIN VideoCategory vc ON vc.videoid = v.videoid
                            " + where+ @"
                            GROUP BY v.videoid, v.title, v.Tags 
                            ORDER BY v.title, v.videoid, v.Tags '

            BEGIN
              EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
            END            
        "
```

the table names are a little different than I started out with, but the main changes are that I made the JOIN into a LEFT JOIN to include videos that had not yet been marked with a category.  Also, I included a where clause.